# Undying vs first strike

Tags: magic-the-gathering

What happens when an **undying** creature dies being dealt damage by a creature with **first strike** in a combat?

For example:

If **[Nearheath Stalker](http://gatherer.wizards.com/pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=262681)** blocks an **[Abattoir Ghoul](http://magiccards.info/isd/en/85.html)** and dies will he deal combat damage after returning to the battlefield? Will Abattoir Ghoul die after this battle?

Comment: For the same reasons, if the *Abattoir Ghoul* had somehow gained *double strike*, it wouldn't kill both the pre-destruction and post-destruction *Nearheath Stalker* creatures.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, the creature returned to the battlefield by undying is considered a new creature because it changed zones (two times, from battlefield to graveyard and then back from graveyard to battlefield). It's not in combat, and won't deal combat damage to Abattoir Ghoul.

> 400.7. **An object that moves from one zone to another becomes a new object with no memory of, or relation to, its previous existence**.
>   There are seven exceptions to this rule:

This rule has some exceptions, but undying isn't one of them.

Answer (score 2):

Your Stalker won't be dealing any combat damage this turn.  When a creature changes zones, it is removed from combat.  (In addition, any time a creature leaves the battle field and comes back it is considered a new game object in terms of the rules.  It generally has no memory of its previous state, such as "I was blocking that.")

Answer (score 1):

No, dead creatures are removed from combat. They are no longer attacking/blocking creatures when combat damage is assigned or dealt.

> 506.4. A permanent is removed from combat if it leaves the battlefield, [...] A creature that's removed from combat stops being an attacking, blocking, blocked, and/or unblocked creature. [...]
>
> 510 **Combat Damage Step**
>
> 510.1. First, the active player announces how each attacking creature assigns its combat damage, then the defending player announces how each blocking creature assigns its combat damage. [...]